# docker share OS volume between services

Tags: docker-compose

This is an extract from Volume configuration reference, in docker docs.

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: db
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/db
  backup:
    image: backup-service
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/backup/data

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Can I have something similar mapped to a custom directory, instead of /var/lib/docker/volumes/?

Something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: db
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/db
  backup:
    image: backup-service
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/backup/data

volumes:
  data-volume: /home/user/db
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19990#issuecomment-248955005

You will have to create the volume with docker cli.